# How to save a Matlab output in a text file

Tags: matlab, text-files

```
ans = 

    'C4'        ''      ''          'eighth note' 
    'C4'        ''      ''          'eighth note' 
    'C4'        ''      ''          'half note'   
    'G4'        ''      ''          'quarter note'
```

This is the output of a matlab code of variable 'ans'. I want to save this result in a different text file. What are the steps should I follow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to read up on the [basics](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf). Here you can find a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

There are few functions that allow you to save the data to a file.

To save data to a file in a specifically formatted way, you can use [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html):

```
x = 0:.1:1;
A = [x; exp(x)];

fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s\n','x','exp(x)');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.8f\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

To simply save workspace variables to a file you can use [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html):

```
p = rand(1,10);
q = ones(10);
save('pqfile.mat','p','q')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this 2nd code.                                                                       p = ans;
save('test1.mat','p') like this. But it didn't work correctly. I have no idea about the rand(1,10) and ones(10). I want to save the output 'ans' that i mention before as a readable notation. I have tried this one also.             p = ans;                                                                      save('pqfile.mat','p','-ascii'). I didn't get a correct result. Please guide me.

Comment: @Lakshi, Can you show us your code? Is your data actually stored in a variable called `ans`? It's just that Matlab prints data to the console with a preceding `ans = ` regardless of what the original variable was called. I'm guessing that you don't actually have a variable `ans` and that's why saving isn't working properly

Comment: I have 5 classes(convertsong,findfrequencies,FrequiencyToNote,noteDuration,timeout) which are used to get this answer.  So Do you need all the classes or only the main class?

Comment: @VictorMarchuk there is actually a temporary variable `ans` which stores unassigned values. Try `137.7; ans`.

Comment: @VictorMarchuk, Sir, Thank you for your contribution. I simply want is that above Matlab output(ans) save in a text file as it is in separate columns. I tried these below commands. (save s.txt -v6 -mat) and (save st.txt -ascii). I got the text file.But the saving text file is not readable. Please could you mention that commands are correct or wrong for my task. And give some correct path for that task. Thank you.

Comment: @Lakshi, `save st.txt -ascii` should work, but it will save ALL variables in the workspace, which is probably not what you need. You need to write something like `save st.txt var -ascii` where `var` is a variable that holds your data. I would like to see the code that prints this data. Do you just call some function and it gets printed? If so, something like that might work: `var = youFunction(); save st.txt var -ascii`

Answer (score 0):

Starting in R2019a, you can use "writematrix" function to write a matrix to a file.

```
% M Your variable
% N your output

M = [C4,G4];
writematrix(M,N, "M.txt");
```